# code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE

Tags: c#, refresh-token, microsoft-partnercenter-java

While trying to get custom domains for customers using partner center API, We were using APP only authentication to fetch custom domains but We need to go with APP + USER authentication to fetch custom domains. We have tried APP + USER authentication by using below link:

[APP+USER](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_url=http://localhost)

We had implemented the code for the same to allow APP + USER authentication. Our SPA(React JS Application) will give the auth code, and SPA will call one service to process that request to partner center API to generate refresh token and access token through auth code and store that refresh token to key vault. But while processing request, we are unable to get token

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE.\r\nTrace ID: 3b5b5d7c-a680-4ccf-ab2c-a474d9196b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 370937cc-3272-4b06-b089-9c5978485fb5\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-23 12:43:24Z","error_codes":[50148],"timestamp":"2020-11-23 12:43:24Z","trace_id":"3b5b5d7c-a680-4ccf-ab2c-a474d9196b00","correlation_id":"370937cc-3272-4b06-b089-9c5978485fb5","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50148"}

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.\r\nTrace ID: 14c9cba0-90c5-4f84-9a0b-472d1923a500\r\nCorrelation ID: 784cf9c2-c571-4cbe-9b0c-15ef71bb276d\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-24 11:02:03Z","error_codes":[9002327],"timestamp":"2020-11-24 11:02:03Z","trace_id":"14c9cba0-90c5-4f84-9a0b-472d1923a500","correlation_id":"784cf9c2-c571-4cbe-9b0c-15ef71bb276d"}
```